# Convert OFString to string or char in DCMTK

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, dcmtk

I am trying to extract the instance number from a DICOM image using dcmtk. The code is shown below:

```
DcmFileFormat fileformat;
    OFCondition status = fileformat.loadFile(src_path);
    if (status.good())
      {
        OFString instanceNumber=0;
        if (fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_InstanceNumber, instanceNumber).good())
        {
            std::cout << "instance Number N: " << instanceNumber << std::endl;
            sprintf(instanceNum, "%s\n", instanceNumber);

            printf("%s\n", instanceNum);
        }
        else
            std::cerr << "Error: cannot access instance Number!" << std::endl;
       }
    else
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")" << std::endl;
```

Now I got the instance number,but I want to copy the instance number into a char or string( for further programming).But as the number is an OFString,how do I convert it into the required datatype. Any thoughts?

Comment: And how come this is C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dcmtk to directly read into the requested data type with the findAndGetXXX-methods. In your particular case the VR of the Instance Number is IS, so the method to use is findAndGetSint32. See: [here](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classDcmItem.html#59ef3ee442b03d50774710898c600156).

Applied to your code:

```
DcmFileFormat fileformat;
OFCondition status = fileformat.loadFile(src_path);
if (status.good())
  {
    SInt32 instanceNumber=0;
    if (fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetSint32(DCM_InstanceNumber, &instanceNumber).good())
    {
        std::cout << "instance Number N: " << instanceNumber << std::endl;
        sprintf(instanceNum, "%d\n", instanceNumber);

        printf("%d\n", instanceNum);
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot access instance Number!" << std::endl;
   }
else
    std::cerr << "Error: cannot read DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")" << std::endl;
```

shoud be working...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, OFString implements a subset of std::string, so you can use c_str() if you want to get a "const char*" as other people already suggested. Alternatively, you could also compile the DCMTK with HAVE_STD_STRING defined and OFString would be identical to std::string.

All this is also described in the documentation, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You use [`c_str()`](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classOFString.html#1be46327ce2039e51f622ca976f2cbb2) to get a `const char*` and create a `string` based on that if you want.

```
std::string s(instanceNumber.c_str());
```

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai  I did

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (e.g. Debian), the operating system provides the packages compiled with the flag `DCMTK_ENABLE_STL` disabled. Patching the package is not a good idea, because then you'd have to recompile every package that depends on it.

But sometimes you do need a `std::string` and an `OFString` won't do. To convert an `OFString` to an `std::string` in general, you can use the following snippet:

```cpp
std::string str(ofstr.data(), ofstr.length());
```

which also copies any embedded zeros if there are any.